# How to return a function for number guessing game

Tags: python, function, return

I am having trouble getting a program to return the right values correctly.

The problem: 
Using Python, you are writing a number guessing program where the player must try to guess the secret number 25. This function will take a player's guess and tell them if they are either right or whether they should guess higher or lower on their next turn

Write a function named "higher_lower" that takes an int as a parameter and returns "higher" if 25 is greater than the input and "lower" if 25 is less than the input, and "correct" if 25 is equal to the input.

My current code:

```
def higher_lower(num):
    if num > 25:
        print("higher")
    elif num < 25:
        print("lower")
    else:
        print("correct")
    return **[......]**
```

I've tried all of the following: higher_lower, higher_lower(num), and just num but all either give an EOF error or return an actual numerical value instead of word. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Use `return 'lower'` and `return 'higher'` instead of print. So you'll get 'lower' and 'higher' respectively in the console.

Like:

```
def higher_lower(num):
if num > 25:
   return "higher"
elif num < 25:
    return "lower"
else:
    return "correct"
```

Or you can use both, print and return, but paste print statement before return, if you want to follow this way.

Comment: Also the logic is wrong as per the requirement "returns "higher" if 25 is greater than the input "